# Android capture all motion events and dispatch them to children

Tags: android, touch, scrollview, viewflipper, swipe

Alright, this is giving me headache for over an hour. I've got several ScrollViews in ViewFlipper. I want to implement swipe left/right gesture while letting the scrollview to scroll. The idea is quite simple - intercept the event and viewflipper, parse it and pass it to the children no matter what happened. This way I can easily detect the swipe without making mess with the events.

Theoretically all I have to do is to handle onTouch or something like that and return false, so the event will be dispatched to children. But the Android is so smart he won't send my any other events than `ACTION_DOWN` if I return false, because it thinks I don't want them.

So how can I capture **all** the motion events coming to the ViewFlipper and it's children and still dispatch them to the children? I can handle detecting the swipe myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is very nasty about this kind of things. You have to subclass and implement dispatchTouchEvent the way you need. Or you can grab some android code and modify it. I tried to use onInterceptTouchEvent() but found it unusable.

Answer (score 1):

check out `onInterceptTouchEvent()` for a view group, if you wish to analyze the touches on view flipper and return false to pass the actions to the child views. look at the following link for more information.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)